# Error(3,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: Column is not allowed here

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, compiler-errors

I am writing following oracle sql trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scheme1.INSERTING_TRIGGER AFTER INSERT  ON scheme1.Bill
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO scheme2.DM_LOGGER(ID, TECHNOLOGY, WORKFLOW, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT)
    VALUES(scheme1.Bill.id,'Repository','UP','Accepted', SYSDATE);   
    END;
```

And it throws following errors:

- Error(2,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
- Error(3,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: Column isn't allowed here.

If my guess is correct, the problem is in the ID column of the DM_LOGGER.
But I'm not sure what wrong it is about. I just want to insert the id from a new Bill record automatically in my logger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `NEW` record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scheme1.INSERTING_TRIGGER AFTER INSERT  ON scheme1.Bill
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO scheme2.DM_LOGGER(ID, TECHNOLOGY, WORKFLOW, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT)
    VALUES(:NEW.id,'Repository','UP','Accepted', SYSDATE);   
    END;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955

Comment: Thanks man, this works. I didn't knew about the OLD and NEW variables, thanks!